# webserver access problem

Tags: web-server, local-area-network

I forwarded public IP address to local IP 10.10.101.xxx(server address). On that server is my web. From LAN I have typing 10.10.101.xxx to view website.How to set the LAN to access on my website with dns (www.mysite.com). I have registered domain name.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a DNS A record that points www.mysite.com to the public IP address. Your port forwarding should then do the rest for you.

Comment: I don't known how to create DNS A record. Any manual?

Comment: google for nicolai langfeldt's dns howto

Comment: @Ognjen: The company you registered www.mysite.com may provide tools to allow you to do this on their DNS servers. Check with them and see.

Comment: @lain: you not understand me. The company who is registered  www.mysite.com form me is already set www.mysite.com to my public IP.Problem: In LAN where is my webserver I can't see website if type www.mysite.com but can see this website only when type local IP of webserver(10.10.101.xxx).How to view website from LAN when type www.mysite.com

Comment: Do you have a DNS server on your LAN - if you do which one is it ? If not then what do the hosts on your LAN use for DNS ?

Comment: No, I don't have DNS server in my LAN. In LAN I have server with address(10.10.101.xxx). Public address is static and forwarded to 10.10.101.xxx. www.mysite.com is domain name for my public static IP (this registered on some company). Users from LAN have type 10.10.101.xxx to view website on server.

Comment: Users want to access to the site typing www.mysite.com but now it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, you have at least two options:

1. Set up [split horizon DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-horizon_DNS), so that your LAN clients get the local LAN IP address (10.10.101.xxx) of your website, and the rest of the world gets the public IP address. OR:
2. Set up [hairpin NAT](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Hairpin_NAT) (a.k.a. NAT loopback, a.k.a. NAT inside-to-inside) on your gateway router, so that requests to your web server's public IP address from your LAN clients route through your gateway and back in again.

Comment: I have win server 2008 and install DNS server but don't know how to create split horizon DNS (this options is all I want)